# Calculating tangent line at $t=2$

Tags: calculus, tangent-line, slope

> Calculate the tangent line at $t=2$ of the curve
>   $$x(t)=t^2+2t+4,\ y(t)=1+te^t$$

How would you go about determining this? So far I have

$$x'(t)=2t + 2\\
y'(t) = te^t+e^t$$

Where do I go from here to get the tangent line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following expression is how you can find the slope of a parametric curve:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)},\ \frac{dx}{dt}\ne0.
$$

When you have found the slope of the curve at $t=2$, use the equation of a straight line to form the actual line:

$$
y-y_0=m(x-x_0).
$$

Use your original parametric equation to find the point $(x_0,y_0)$ at $t=2$.

Comment: how do you get dy/dt? thats just the derivative of the second equation right?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt}$ means the same thing as $y'(t)$. It's the same thing just different notation.

Comment: @EmilyRichards: You've already found $\frac{dy}{dt}.$ It is $y'(t).$

Comment: ok. what would I plug in for (x0,y0)? would that just be (0,2)?

Comment: $(x_0,y_0)$ should be a point on the curve when $t=2$.

Comment: And is there a formula that you can use to figure out when this point is? or would you have to graph it?

Comment: What formula? As I said, take $t=2$ and plug it into your original parametric equation to get $x_0=x(2)$ and $y_0=y(2)$.

Comment: you just plug in x(2) and y(2)

Comment: ahhh gotcha thanks

Comment: @MichaelRybkin When plugging in 2 into the second original parametric equation, how would you simplify e^2 without a calculator? I evaluated the slope and it's e^t/2.

Comment: I don't think you can simplify it. Do as much arithmetic as possible and then just leave it as it is.

Comment: The tangent line is going to be $y=\frac{e^2}{2}x+1-4e^2$. Use Desmos for parametric equations to plot your curve and the tangent lines: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/keb3qakosf

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

A directing vector of the tangent to the curve at the point $M_2$ with coordinates$(x(2),y(2))$ is the vector
$$\vec v=(x'(2),y'(2)),$$
hence a point $M(x,y)$ is on this tangent line if and only if the vectors $\overrightarrow{M_2M}$ and $\vec v$ are collinear, i.e. the determinant of their coordinates is $0$.